# ¿Cómo guardar un array asociativo traído desde AJAX hasta PHP en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Bien, tengo esta situación: extraigo datos desde una lista y los paso mediante AJAX hasta PHP en un array. Los datos llegan correctamente en un array asociativo. El problema es que no sé como separar los datos por elementos para actualizar en la base de datos cada fila de valores según la `id` de cada elemento.

```
    var hora;
    var izq;
    var clase;
    var idEntrada;
    var datos = [];
    $('#publicar').on('click',function() {
        hora = $('#horaDesp').val();
        izq = $('#despIzq').children('section');
        izq.each(function() {
            clase = $(this).attr('class');
            idEntrada = $(this).children('div').attr('id');
            clase = clase.substr(8,2);
            datos.push({
                'id': idEntrada,
                'clase': clase
            });
        });
        datos = {
            datos,
            'hora': hora
        }
        console.log(datos);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/funciones/programar.php',
            data: datos
    }).done(function(response) {
            // $(".resultado").html(response);
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
```

Los datos se mandan de esta manera por AJAX a PHP y se reciben así:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['datos'])) {
$datos = $_POST['datos'];
$hora = $_POST['hora'];

foreach($datos as $dato) {
print_r($dato);
}
```

Cuando se usa el `print_r` se pueden ver los datos en array's separados. Por Ejemplo:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 18
    [clase] => _b
)
Array
(
    [id] => 20
    [clase] => _b
)
```

Pero si necesito solo seleccionar la `id` para buscarlo en la base de datos mediante `$dato['id']` al hacer un `print_r` se juntan todas las id's, en este caso el resultado sería `1820` en lugar de

```
Array
(
    18
)
Array
(
    20
)
```

O cualquier formato que me permita separarlos, es un ejemplo.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso ocurre por `$dato` es a su vez un array que está anidado dentro del array principal, entonces, para obtener el `id` por ejemplo en cada paso del array puedes hacer esto:

```
foreach($datos as $dato) {
     if ( is_array($dato) ) { #Esto lo hacemos como simple control
        foreach ($dato as $row) {
            #Aquí puedes ir reuniendo los ids en una variable si quisieras
            echo $dato["id"]; 
            echo $dato["clase"].PHP_EOL; 

         }
     }
}
```

O, si quieres mostrar cada clave valor:

```
foreach($datos as $dato) {
     if ( is_array($dato) ) { #Esto lo hacemos como simple control
        foreach ($dato as $k=>$v) {
            #Aquí puedes ir reuniendo los datos en una variable si quisieras
            echo "$k: \t $v \n"; 
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario  @Cedano! Ok, pero ¿cómo realizo la inserción a la base de datos? Dame un ejemplo de cómo puedo extraer la `id` del primer elemento en una variable para usarla en la estructura sql

Comment: @KdisellQ tienes que conectar a la base de datos y usar lo que hay en `$datos` para construir tu consulta y mandarla a ejecución. Eso ya se aleja del tema inicial de tu pregunta. Aquí hay varios ejemplos de cómo se hace, porque depende de si usas mysqli, PDO, etc. Intenta y si tienes problemas o errores plantea una nueva pregunta.